# How do I find all the coefficients of $x^0$ in this: $(x-\frac{2}{\sqrt x})^8$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How do I find all the coefficients of $x^0$ in this: $(x-\frac{2}{\sqrt x})^8$

I got to $8 - k + (-0.5)k = 0$ and then $ 16 - 3k = 0 $ and thus, I can't find $k$ that will solve this equation. What do u guys think?

Comment: There is no $x^0$ term in the expansion.

Comment: ...Because 3 does not divide 8.

Comment: @Did So my solution is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Binomial Theorem states that 
$$(a + b)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^{n - k}b^k$$
Here, $a = x$, $b = -\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$, and $n = 8$.  Hence,
$$\left(x - \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^8 = \sum_{k = 0}^{8} \binom{8}{k} x^{8 - k}\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^k$$
For the $x^0$ term to exist, we require that 
$$x^{8 - k}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^k = x^{8 - k}(x^{-\frac{1}{2}})^k = x^{8 - k}x^{-\frac{k}{2}} = x^{8 - \frac{3k}{2}} = x^0$$
Since the bases are the same, the exponents must be equal.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
8 - \frac{3k}{2} & = 0\\
16 - 3k & = 0\\
-3k & = 16\\
k & = \frac{16}{3}
\end{align*}
Since $k$ is not an integer, there is no $x^0$ term in the binomial expansion of 
$$\left(x - \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^8$$

Comment: Exactly what I did in my mind. Thank you! :) NOTE: as long as one knows the binomial theorem, it is easy from there.